# Could not create project in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Can any one tell me why this type of error message is prompting when i am creating new project.

The error message is as below.

> " Could not load file or assembly .
>
> 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.ManagedInterfaces, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,PublicKey Token=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies.
>
> The system cannot find the file specified."

What should I do to overcome this?

Comment: What type of new project are you trying to create?

Comment: Looks like an old VS2005 assembly.  Try disabling add-ons.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the "Repair" option on then VS2010 Setup will help. If not you might have to do a complete uninstall/reboot/install cycle.

A quick google search gave me something pointing at the VS SDK - maybe a reinstall of this might help too.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue after installation SP1. I tried re-install of SP1 with no success.

Get the Microsoft.VisualStudio.ManagedInterfaces.dll(if it is not present in your environment you can [download it from here](http://www.getdll.org/en-us/download/4523) ) and install to global cache. Restart VS2010 and load you project again.