# VS 2010 - could not create any new projects

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I have been creating and running projects in VS 2010 using Windows 7 Prof. and all of a sudden, my system hung, and i had to restart my computer, without closing the existing 4 projects in VS2010, which was open.

When i rebooted and tried to open my VS2010, i am getting Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.ManagedInterfaces, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=nuetral, PublicKeytoken=b03f57f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies.  The system cannot fine the file specified". [Please see the attached fig. ][image]

I have googled, and there is even a posting [here^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131890/could-not-create-project-in-visual-studio-2010) in StackOverflow, without any resolution

Also, some other site suggested copying the Micorosoft.VisualStudio.ManagedInterfaces.dll from C:\Windows\assembly from another computer and paste it into the problematic one , but i am not able to copy the dll, either.

Any idea how to fix this ?

Comment: If you have the CD or the ISO, I'd start with a repair install.

Comment: Hi @BradChristie, unfortunately, i do not have the CD..

Comment: @Ron then download the trial iso from microsoft

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If not having the install media should not be an issue, 2010 and above should download it automatically for you.

open program and features (add remove programs) and run the repair option, if that does not work you may need to do a clean install.

Comment: did you try it? when i run it has always gotten from the net

Comment: Thanks @workabyte, after the 2nd try, when i clicked "download", it automatically started downloading from the net. Now, all is good, and able to open the old projects and new ones. Thanks.!!

Comment: @ron no problem, i have had to repair my install many times :| glad you got it going.